# Triple venti meaning at Starbucks

Tags: espresso, starbucks

At Starbucks I asked for venti with an extra shot. The barista called it a triple venti. What does the triple mean? I thought and a Google search confirmed that a venti comes with 3 espresso shots, so what does the triple refer to?

Comment: I was wrong about the number of shots in a venti, I will only order grandes from now on. Grandes and venti both have 2 shots of espresso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refers to those shots of espresso. You have 2 in there by default. (The *iced* Venti drinks typically get 3, because the cup is a little larger (24 oz.))